# Checked and disabled checkboxes for non-changing setup

Tags: forms, checkboxes, default

I'm designing the setup UI for a contact form. By default, the contact form will always have 4 fundamental fields: *first name*, *last name*, *e-mail* and *message*.

As a new feature, we are enabling an "Advanced" contact form, that can hold some other input fields, like a *date picker*, *time picker* and a select for the *number of peoples*.

Users will be able to activate the Advanced contact form toggling a select and checking new input fields to enable.

I was wondering if it was better:

- [Minimal] to display only the customisable part of the setup form, once the Advanced form is enabled
- [Complete] to always show the 4 basic fields (that cannot be modified), and then display the additional fields that can be customised

[image: Demo of the Minimal and Complete version]

If it was about me, I'd probably always show the advanced form mode of the Complete example, without a distinction between a Standard and an Advanced mode; however, due to marketing reasons, this distinction has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the rest of you UI. Here is one way of doing it.

Reveal advanced form options on click.

[image: Contact form setup UI]

Not sure why you have used drop-downs, but they are unnecessary, unless  dictated by the application logic.